# wix burn ExePackage doesnt run on uninstall

Tags: installation, wix, burn, wix3.11

I'm trying to run a bundled installation using WIX burn, and it works fine for the install process. The problem is the uninstallation - the ExePackage that I want to run during the uninstall doesn't run. To verify, I write to the log every time I run it, I get a new record in the log during the installation but I don't get one during the uninstall. The package source file is InstallElasticSearch.exe (the second in the chain), and nothing I tried so far worked. I've tried changing the "Permanent" property, changing the order of it in the chain and removing the UninstallCommand.

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Web"/>
  <MsiPackage Id="elasticzip" SourceFile="..\..\..\ReportsSetup\bin\Release\ReportsSetup.msi" DisplayName="Copying files"/>
  <ExePackage After="elasticzip" SourceFile="InstallElasticSearch.exe" Permanent="no" UninstallCommand="uninstall" DisplayName="Elasticsearch reporting services"/>
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\..\..\SetupProject3\bin\Release\EsyDeploySetup.msi" DisplayName="App and plugin" />
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\..\..\OvlInstaller\bin\Release\OvlInstaller.msi" DisplayName="Admin services"/>
  <ExePackage SourceFile="package3.exe" Permanent="yes" InstallCommand="[ProgramFilesFolder]" DisplayName="Add shared folder"/>
  <ExePackage SourceFile="ChangeServiceCreds.exe" Permanent="yes" DisplayName="Setting windows service credentials"/>
  <ExePackage SourceFile="package1.exe" Permanent="yes" DisplayName="Checking active sessions"/>
  <ExePackage SourceFile="package2.exe" Permanent="yes" DisplayName="Setting setup process data"/>
</Chain>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like WIX wont run an ExePackage on uninstall if the ExePackage element doesn't have a  DetectCondition property. MsiPackage would run, it's only for the ExePackage. Silly me, how could I have missed such an obvious thing?

Comment: The `InstallElasticSearch.exe` package would be an error in v4 since it's non-permanent and doesn't have `DetectCondition`. The other packages also don't have `DetectCondition` but are permanent so it would be a warning on all of those.