# WIX Uninstall an EXE Package

Tags: wix

I am working on a wix installer that Installs WebView2. I have this working. However, when I uninstall WebView2 is left on my system. How do I remove the WebView2 when the uninstaller is ran?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" >
    <Bundle Name="Build.Bootstrap.Installer" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company Name" UpgradeCode="GUID">
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>
        <Chain>
            <ExePackage Id="InvokeBootstrapper" Name="Install WebView2 Runtime" Cache="no" Compressed="no" 
PerMachine="yes" Vital="yes" SourceFile="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe" 
InstallCommand=" /silent /install" InstallCondition="NOT (REMOVE OR WVRTInstalled)" /> 

            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Do you really want to do that? What if another application installed it and is depending on it?

If you're wondering what WiX needs then see related questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521772/wix-burn-exepackage-doesnt-run-on-uninstall for `DetectCondition` and `UninstallCommand`.

If you're wondering what to put in `DetectCondition` and `UninstallCommand` then that's something specific to WebView2 that Microsoft hopefully has documentation on. It would be nice if someone would contribute this back to WiX so everyone can easily add this to their bundle.

Comment: @SeanHall that is a fair question. When I think about the uninstall in that way, I do not want to uninstall it. Thanks!